# +What could prevent the func scrollViewDidScroll not being called in a UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, scrollview

I have already set up in the viewDidLoad()

tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self

the tableView use static cell and the UIScrollViewDelegate is already part of the UITableViewController...

I made some research on this issue and every time it was because of the delegate not being set. But I did it and the func is still not being called.

Any idea on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid error.

I just had to change

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

to

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {